# Preventing word-wrap for kendo dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an example of a KendoDropDownList [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ihatemash/4933xwhq/)

```
var ds = [
    {label:"External Causes of Morbidity, Mortality"},
    {label:"Cardiovascular"},
    {label:"Circulatory System Diseases"},
    {label:"Codes of Special Purposes"},
    {label:"Congenital Anomalies"},
    {label:"Digestive System Diseases"},
    {label:"Easr and Mastoid Process Disease"},
    {label:"Endocrine, Metabolic, Immunity"}];

$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: 'label',
    dataSource: ds    
});

var ddl = $("#dropdownlist").data('kendoDropDownList').list.width("auto");
```

As you can see, I have the list's width set to "auto" but the first item in the list still word-wraps. I thought the "auto" value caused the window to fit to the correct size of the largest item in the list or do I have to just figure out the correct width needed and hard-code the width to prevent word-wrapping?

Comment: Seems like some sort of bug.  Setting `list.width("auto")` does expand the list width but just not enough for that one item.  If you have Telerik support you might want to point them to your jsFiddle and see what they say.

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs about list.width("auto") - where did you find that?  Setting this width of the #dropdownlist element would make it wider, but I'm not sure about an auto method.

Comment: I found it [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-should-take-size-of-biggest-option)  I am also using it and it works for the most part but there are some times when an item wraps.

Comment: Thanks once again Rick.  I'll make sure to do that since I do have support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to tell the listitems to not wrap text as well as setting the width to auto:

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: 'label',
    dataSource: ds,    
    dataBound: function(e) {
        e.sender.list.width("auto");
    }
});

.k-list-container .k-list .k-item
{
    padding-right: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4933xwhq/1/)**

If you prefer to do it all in code:

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: 'label',
    dataSource: ds,    
    dataBound: function(e) {
        e.sender.list.width("auto").find("li").css({"white-space": "nowrap", "padding-right": "25px"});
    }
});
```

> **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4933xwhq/2/)**

NOTE: the right padding leaves space for the vertical scrollbar.